# $statement->num_rows returning 0

Tags: php, return

Im trying do a login system with email confirmation, so when the user confirm the email the value of hash in the database changes from a MD5 value to "confirmed", then in the logon.php I used:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $confirmed = 'confirmed';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND hash = ? AND password = SHA(?) LIMIT 1";
    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $confirmed);

    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();

    if ($statement->num_rows == 1)
    {
        $statement->bind_result($_SESSION['userid'], $_SESSION['username']);
        $statement->fetch();
        header ("Location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username/password combination is incorrect.";
    }
}
```

I already tried everything, but the `$statement->num_rows` always return 0, anybody can help me? Please

Comment: As aside not, put an `exit` after your `header` redirection line

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for

```
  $statement->rowCount()
```

I hope that helped